# Use ProGuard to Obfuscate private methods in Library

Tags: android, obfuscation

I have been through a lot of questions but none of them are serving my purpose.

Some methods, obfuscate the private field names and nothing else.

I have a class in which there are multiple methods, few of them are very crucial and I don't want other's to reverse engineer them and get the result. So I was kinda looking for some method by which I can hide the code of private methods or obfuscate in such a way that they can't get the head and tail of it.

Moreover, I have that as a library i.e JAR file.

Let's say the code are as follows :

```
public void methodStart(Context context) {
        // I'll call the private method coldstart
        coldStart(context);
    }

private void coldStart(Context context) {
        // some calculations

    }
private void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
        //my work
    }
```

I tried ProGuard :

```
release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

but it's not working. Is it even doable?

Thanks.

Comment: So you're looking to keep the method names but obfuscate the code inside right?

Comment: Yeaah. Exactly that.

Comment: You can't really do that. You can hide methods by making them synthetic (A few obfuscators can do this. This will prevent JD-GUI from showing anything). There's a few tricks you can do to make specific decompilers fail but there will always be a way to reverse engineer the source.

Comment: I agree. If we look at the libraries of few big companies, they don't really have anything in the java files but they do get the work done. E.g. "Indoor Atlas", how do they do that?

Comment: Don't really feel like signing up to check their plugin, but you can minify your library at least if that's what you're talking about. I've used a few libraries that did this (Encrypted names of private classes / fields / methods, public classes / fields/ methods were left untouched) It's pretty easy to accomplish with Proguard too using -keep.